# When I send an email to a gmail account with Sendgrid, the HREF changes

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, gmail, sendgrid

I send an email via Sendgrid to a Gmail address.

**Link creator code**

```
var selfUrl = "https://dev.api.x.com"
var link = $"<a href=\"{selfUrl}/api/app/auth/email-confirm/{HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code)}\" target=\"_blank\">clicking here</a>."
```

**Result**

```
<a href="http://url2616.x.com/ls/click?upn=O1koG4mHVXocX18C7ui-2BIcWm7u1tquqDfaIf7sa7T1cRdXsxkkd80g4oQpJcIwO6ssIaLQni2wNsHLut7xNECryLlyiRjQhfD6HMbuSDhIkLCypNYwW2a6Qok4-2BTh-2FbZClbpNLkeNMcoKQuvFGrhJxKVmfacj-2BiCs-2B62J2QpCTLWwAMaleNwImS8dssM6T25Rz8oMkM3zDxndtaQdUpSr3WOW5zYDJyCgkeeQliWDkE78Xl0iFPR-2BnhZWlA9d6kYK11zcomE64g-2Bl75shHultfNVxVF3mMdNZMLPZUtPXyTJtWD3SMGNoAlmA8pToTi8fqi-2BC-2F5jC1t5uCUdKuYdAdlQMIa1IrboChIdgr4U945u38RSayVV7ZdAdEsxFiUxML8rw8-2Br09PSsaKKD5Ywgcu-2B7Y1cc-2Fv0MrlAj4Zpgsrm9Htdc5rq6Au52U83t209FBwKMbuB12Q-3DI8JE_FUVpsP3RhO1yjshN1cDCN0tfLzRrAPM-2FAJDUsUJILSAhNjbQM7e76KCBy0NmXaOdyT0puL7x2p-2BuhOuEX8XU9gawnog-2FXeo-2FLfmqzsBxA1DSWwVUuOCOpm48fgsTj5ns-2FzjAlEmy951AVa4AlGjH6w89dZBA4trEoiCKHKKXfnNNSJ8RowVOhrdpE5VKhRBumwzeVPfwxluZJv3d75aZjOYlw20XCV4aHx0u21gwNjU-3D" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://url2616.x.com/ls/click?upn%3DO1koG4mHVXocX18C7ui-2BILlyiRjQhfD6HMbuSDhIkLCypNYwW2a6Qok4-2BTh-2FbZClbpNLkQHeZ8TkYWMvG01V-2BJ-2BsJeuQZWfF8gRBqR3-2Fwm1LjAGbqeNMcoKQuvFGrhJxKVmfacj-2BiCs-2B62J2QpCTLWwAMaleNwImS8dssM6T25Rz8oMkM3zDxndtaQdUpSr3WOW5zYDJyCgkeeQliWDkE78Xl0iFPR-2BnhZWlA9d6kYK11zcomE64g-2Bl75shHultfNVxVF3mMdNZMLPZUtPXyTJtWD3SMGNoAlmA8pToTi8fqi-2BC-2F5jC1t5uCUdKuYdAdlQMIa1IrboChIdgr4U945u38RSayVV7ZdAdEsxFiUxML8rw8-2Br09PMqMeNjZ5shKcK5xM-2BL2MuV8RjmjPD0EgOOS7loSqyJ4Cik0tmf7NSsaKKD5Ywgcu-2B7Y1cc-2Fv0MrlAj4Zpgsrm9Htdc5rq6Au52U83t209FBwKMbuB12Q-3DI8JE_FUVpsP3RhO1yjshN1cDCN0tfLzRrAPM-2FAJDUsUJILSAhNjbQM7e76KCBy0NmXaOdyT0puL7x2p-2BuhOuEX8XU9gawnog-2FXeo-2FLfmqzsBxA1DSWwVUuOCOpm48fgsTj5ns-2FzjAlEmy951AVa4AlGjH6w89dZBA4trEoiCKHKKXfnNNSJ8RowVOhrdpE5VKhRBumwzeVPfwxluZJv3d75aZjOYlw20XCV4aHx0u21gwNjU-3D&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1700645045818000&amp;usg=AOvVaw0C8GoR7LRnnwMBH1oBv4Kx">clicking here</a>
```

Who (gmail-sendgrid) and Why change HREF ?

Comment: That looks like click tracking? Maybe injected by SendGrid.